# Why is the copy constructor called when we return an object from a method by value

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, return-by-value

why copy constructor is called when we return an object from a method by value. please see my below code in that i am returning an object from a method while returning control is hitting the copy constructor and then returning. i am not understood following things:
 1) why it is calling copy constructor.
 2)which object is passing implicitly to  copy constructor,
 3)to which object copy constructor will copy the content,
 4)what is the necessity of copying the object content while returning. so plz help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
   int a, b;
     public:
   ClassA()
   {
     a = 10;
     b = 20;
   }
   ClassA(ClassA &obj)
   {
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
   }
 };

 ClassA function (ClassA &str)
 {
  return str;
 }

 int main ()
 {
   ClassA str;
   function(str);
   //function(str);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you understand that if an object is returned from a function, then that object must be created?

Comment: why we need to create the object, i am just returning the received object which is constructed in main function only.

Comment: If a function returns an object, it returns _an object_, nothing more and nothing less. The fact that you passed a reference to another object as a parameter does not affect these semantics at all. An object must be returned. the following code: "ClassA str; ClassA str2 = function(str);" *must* end up with *two* objects, str and str2. Only one constructor is simply not going to make it. You need to create _two_ objects.

Comment: okay Daniel now i got ..thanks for your help.

Comment: It is very similar to what happens in your previous question. Semantically, you must return a copy. But that actual copying can be elided.

Comment: [better explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972908/c-copy-constructor-activation-in-return-by-vlaue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy constructor is called because you call by value not by reference. Therefore a new object must be instantiated from your current object since all members of the object should have the same value in the returned instance. Because otherwise you would be returning the object it self, which would be returning by reference. In this case modifying the reference object would change the original as well. This is generally not a behavior one wants when returning by value.

Answer (score 24):

I'll try to answer all the questions at once.

The behavior you are observing is due to the way returning an object by value works in C++. First, a temporary object is copy-constructed (or move-constructed, in C++11) from the value returned by your function. Then, if this return value is used to initialize another object, such as in:

```
Class c = fxn();
```

The object `c` is copy-constructed (or move-constructed, in C++11), from that temporary.

This said, an implementation is allowed to **elide** one (in your concrete case) or both of these calls to the copy or move constructor per paragraph 12/8.31 of the C++11 Standard even though those constructors have side effects, and construct the function's return value directly in `c`:

> When certain criteria are met, **an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects**. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move
>   operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object
>   occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization.122
>   **This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies)**:
>
> — in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object (**other than a function or catch-clause parameter**) with the same cv-unqualified
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value
>
> — [...]
>
> — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
>   to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move
>
> — [...]

The reason why I wrote that in your specific case only one of the calls to the copy or move constructor can be elided is the sentence in bold in the first bullet of the Standard quote above:

> [...] (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) [...]

If you are returning a parameter of your function, copy elision is inhibited.

Also notice, that the signature of your constructor should be:

```
Class(Class const& c)
//          ^^^^^
```

There is no reason for you to accept an lvalue reference to non-`const` in the copy constructor, since you are not going to modify the object you are copying from.

Even worse, the above would prevent copy construction from rvalues (like temporaries), so the following code would not compile:

```
Class foo() { return Class(); }
```

Even though an implementation is allowed to elide the copy, a viable and accessible copy constructor (or move constructor, if we're talking about a move) should still be present.

Comment: you mention that in C++11 this can be done with a move from that temporary. Does this make the temporary a rvalue? And is this more efficient than the copy method as in pre C++11?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Yes, temporaries are rvalues. And yes, many times a move is more efficient than a copy - but moves can also *degrade* to copying if a move constructor is not provided. This said, types of the Standard Library all provide a move constructor.

Comment: @AndyProwl, that's a great answer. In OP's example code, can we know that which of the copy-constructors was elided?

Comment: @AndyProwl : first of all thanks for explaining the details. you mentioned that temporaries are rvalues. Referring to following point : "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) ... omitted copy/move", I tried something like below <br/>
`
A beta()
{
    A a{20};
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    A b = beta();
    return 0;
}
`
Here too both the copy are elided. But a inside function beta is not a rvalue.

Comment: Great explanation. What I do not understand is why the copy constructor should still be present. Indeed, the OP original code would not compile if the copy constructor is deleted. If the compiler is willing to elide the copy constructor even though it has side effects, why insisting that a copy constructor be provided (either explicitly of compiler provided)?

Answer (score 4):

The function returns an object. Hence, that object must exist. Hence, that object must be created from somewhere. Clearly this means that one of its constructors shall be used. The question is, which one?

Since you chose to `return str;`, this is the instruction that shall be used to create it. How else could you use that return instruction to create and return an object and yet not use the copy constructor? It is clear that you need to use `str` to initialize the returned value, so you're not going to use the other option (the parameterless constructor).

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassA function (ClassA &str)
{
  return str;
}
```

object `str` will copy-constructored in a temporary object with type `ClassA` for further usage. However compiler can omit it due to optimization.