# return object from function by value and use it in assignment/copy c'tor c++

Tags: c++, destructor, return-by-value

suppose a function returns an object of class A by value.

```
A f();
```

suppose we have later an assignment/copy c'tor:

```
a = f(); //a is of type A - assignment
A aa = f(); // copy c'tor
```

is the d'tor of the returned object called after the assignment/initiallization?

Comment: Look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16731868/451600

Comment: Maybe, or maybe not. To support what's called "return value optimization" (and "named return value optimization") the standard allows the compiler to optimize most such copies out, so even if (for example) you had a copy constructor that had side effects, you couldn't count on those side effects happening.

Answer (score 0):

If the returned object would be destructed before copy initialization, you would copy in `aa` destructed object. That is something strange.

Return value optimization also can take place, so there would not be any need to copy returned object and the destruct it.