# Why must a coroutine type be move constructible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++17, c++-coroutine

[  This is specific to TS coroutines, VC++17 and later.  Not a duplicate. ]

I am experimenting with experimental coroutines. I defined a coroutine type called "resumable_thing" (It's based on a talk by McNellis in 2016. At present, it has evolved into a primitive one-celled generator.) **The type will not compile unless either a copy-constructor or a move-constructor is defined,** despite the fact that the ctor can never be invoked?

***Why is that?***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <experimental/generator>

using namespace std;
using namespace experimental;
template<class T>
struct resumable_thing {
    struct promise_type {
        T _value;
        resumable_thing get_return_object() {
            return resumable_thing(coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }
        auto initial_suspend() { return suspend_always{}; }
        auto final_suspend() { return suspend_always{}; }
        void return_value(const T& value) {_value = value; }        
        void yield_value(const T&v) { return_value(v); }
    };

    coroutine_handle<promise_type> _coroutine;

    // ???? Why must I define this? ????
    resumable_thing(resumable_thing &&other) {
        assert(false);
        _coroutine = std::move(other._coroutine);
        other._coroutine = nullptr;
    }
    // Member functions 
    void resume() { _coroutine.resume(); }
    auto get() {return _coroutine.promise()._value;}
    auto operator() () { resume(); return get(); }

    // Ctors dtors
    resumable_thing(resumable_thing const&) = delete; 
    resumable_thing& operator=(resumable_thing const&) = delete;
    resumable_thing() = default;

    explicit resumable_thing(coroutine_handle<promise_type> coroutine)
        : _coroutine(coroutine)
    {}

    ~resumable_thing() { if (_coroutine) _coroutine.destroy(); }



};

static
resumable_thing<int> take_five() {
    for (int i = 0; i<5 ; ++i) {
        co_yield i;
    }
    co_return -1;
}

int main() {    
    auto count = take_five();
    for (int i = count(); i >= 0; i=count()) {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ADDED LATER.  I still do not know why VC++ complains. In any case, it is clear what the movers should do, if they do anything, to wit:

```
resumable_thing(resumable_thing &&right_) 
    : coroutine_(right_.coroutine_)
{
    right_.coroutine_ = nullptr;
}

resumable_thing &operator=(resumable_thing &&right_)
{
    if (this != std::addressof(right_)) {
        coroutine_ = right_.coroutine_;
        right_.coroutine_= nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `resumable_thing(resumable_thing &&other)` is not a copy constructor.

Comment: Who down-voted and why?

Comment: That is the move constructor, not the copy constructor. Better read up on move semantics.

Comment: @Defining a regular copy-constructor will also let it compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the copy constructor called when we return an object from a method by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731782/why-is-the-copy-constructor-called-when-we-return-an-object-from-a-method-by-val). This should be valid for C++17 with guaranteed elision.

Comment: Took the liberty of reverting to the initial edit (where there were no two copy c'tors) and updating the title.

Comment: @StoryTeller - In any case, VC++ will not compile the thing unless there is some kind of copy-contructor, either regular or a mover. Supplying either will make it work.  The code from the McNellis talk will not compile either, and for the same reason.

Comment: I suspect it's an implementation quirk. I really don't see a reason for this to fail. Hopefully someone who is familiar with Microsoft's' implementation of the TS will come along.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I love your work with Penn Jillette, BTW.

Comment: @JiveDadson - Ha! Dude's one of my role models. I wonder what gave it away :P

Comment: How to clear that "possible duplicate"? @user657267, take note that the ctor calls `assert (false);`. It is definitely not being called.

Comment: @JiveDadson Before C++17 the fact that a compiler elides your copy constructor doesn't remove the obligation for you to provide one.

Comment: @user657267 "Before C++17" does not apply to this question. "After C++17" would. C++20, we hope.