# Why must the return type of a coroutine be move-constructible?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

Consider the following code that defines the `invoker` class - a minimal return type for a coroutine.  We explicitly delete the copy and move constructors of the `invoker` class.

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <cstdlib>
class invoker {
public:
    class invoker_promise {
    public:
        invoker get_return_object() { return invoker{}; }
        auto initial_suspend() { return std::suspend_never{}; }
        auto final_suspend() { return std::suspend_never{}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() { std::abort(); }
    };
    using promise_type = invoker_promise;
    invoker() {}
    invoker(const invoker&) = delete;
    invoker& operator=(const invoker&) = delete;
    invoker(invoker&&) = delete;
    invoker& operator=(invoker&&) = delete;
};

invoker f() {
    co_return;
}
```

The code does not compile on [latest GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/C7D4aQ) (10.1), which is supposed to have full support for C++20 coroutines.

Instead, we get an error that indicates that the move constructor is required:

```
<source>: In function 'invoker f()':
<source>:23:1: error: use of deleted function 'invoker::invoker(invoker&&)'
   23 | }
      | ^
<source>:17:5: note: declared here
   17 |     invoker(invoker&&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

Why is this so?

The `invoker` object is constructed by calling `get_return_object()` of the `invoker_promise`, it can't be accessed except from the caller of `f()`.  With C++17 guaranteed copy elision, the `invoker` returned by `get_return_object()` is a prvalue, and hence should not be materialized until after it is returned from `f()`.

Since the returned object cannot be accessed from within the coroutine, I cannot see any situation where we might need to materialize the object before returning it.  Am I missing something?

Note:  I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49725863/1021959), but it:

- was asked two years ago,
- is about the TS version of coroutines,
- is about VC++'s implementation,
- is unanswered, and
- has comments that mainly talk about guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: "*has comments that mainly talk about guaranteed copy elision.*" Guaranteed elision is what you're asking about. The return value of a coroutine function call is a prvalue, but the path to that prvalue getting there is different. Guaranteed elision only works for prvalues, so the question is whether the path from its source to the caller of the coroutine function purely uses prvaues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With C++17 guaranteed copy elision, the `invoker` returned by `get_return_object()` is a prvalue, and hence should not be materialized until after it is returned from `f()`.

That would only be true if a coroutine function call were guaranteed to generate its return value by a call equivalent to building a bunch of objects in a separate stack, then calling `get_return_object()` on one of them. That is, the question is whether the path from `get_return_object()` to the function call itself only uses prvalues.

Let's look at [what the standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct.def.coroutine-7):

> The expression `promise.get_­return_­object()` is used to initialize the glvalue result or prvalue result object of a call to a coroutine. The call to `get_­return_­object` is sequenced before the call to `initial_­suspend` and is invoked at most once.

Note that it says that it initializes the "prvalue result object". This is the same language used in the definition of the [behavior of the `return` statement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.return#2):

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function call by copy-initialization from the operand.

The only hesitation I would have in saying that the standard clearly requires guaranteed elision between `get_return_object` and the caller of the coroutine is the last part about `initial_suspend`. Because something happens *between* the initialization of the "prvalue result object" and returning control to the caller, it could be that there has to be an intermediary, which must be copied/moved from.

But the fact that it's using the exact same language as `return` suggests that it ought to be providing the exact same *behavior* too.

When running on MSVC's coroutine implementation, your code (with only minor changes for differences in where certain types are defined) [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/P9GuA6). Coupled with the above evidence, I would say that this suggests that this is a compiler bug.

Comment: (thanks for the edit, makes the answer hugely better)

Comment: Your godbolt.org link does not seem to have any code.  I think you've forgotten to click the "share" button before copying the link?

Comment: @Bernard: Fixed.

Comment: Am I correct to say that compiler magic is necessary to call any function (e.g. `initial_suspend`) while ensuring that the prvalue result object returned by a previous function call (e.g. `get_return_object`) is never materialized? (ignoring the fact that coroutines require compiler magic anyway)

Comment: @Bernard: Are you asking if there's any mechanism in C++ to declare a prvalue, initialize it, then go do something else unrelated to that initialization, and then return it? No. Not in C++20.

Comment: Yes, indeed that's what I'm asking in the comment above.  If it isn't possible in C++20, then the compiler would need additional magic to ensure that `invoker` is never moved.

Comment: @Bernard: What do you mean by "additional magic"? It'd just be the same "magic" as any copy elision case: initializing the return value object directly rather than through an intermediary.

Comment: @NicolBolas  Presumably the compiler would have to synthesize some code that calls `get_return_object` and `initial_suspend`, and then return the prvalue obtained from `get_return_object`.  Since saving the value obtained from `get_return_object` as a prvalue across the call to `initial_suspend` isn't possible in C++, the compiler would need additional magic to save it.

Comment: @Bernard: As I said, it's the same "magic" as copy elision. Or how do you think NRVO works?

Comment: @Oliv: No; that's about how `co_return` works. This is about how the return value object of a coroutine gets generated. Those are different mechanisms.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, I didn't realise that it is precisely NRVO.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in GCC 10.2, but it is currently present in Clang trunk, [bug reported](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53098). Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9sYj1qMnc