# Must coroutine return type be copy- or move-constructible if it is passed in co_await

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, coroutine

In the following code example, the lambda coroutine `g` performs `co_await f`, where `f` is coroutine return type with deleted copy- and move- constructors:

```
#include <coroutine>

class task {
public:
    class task_promise {
    public:
        task get_return_object() { return task{handle_type::from_promise(*this)}; }
        auto initial_suspend() { return std::suspend_always{}; }
        auto final_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
    };
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<task_promise>;
    handle_type handle;

    auto await_ready() { return false; }
    auto await_suspend(handle_type) { return handle; }
    void await_resume() { handle.resume(); }

    using promise_type = task_promise;
    task(handle_type h) : handle(h) {}
    task(const task&) = delete;
    task& operator=(const task&) = delete;
    task(task&&) = delete;
    task& operator=(task&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    task f = []() -> task { co_return; }();
    task g = [&f]() -> task { co_await f; }();
    g.handle.resume();
}
```

The code is accepted in MSVC, but not in GCC.

GCC 11.2 complains on the missing move-constructor:

```
error: use of deleted function 'task::task(task&&)'
```

and GCC trunk - on the missing copy-constructor:

```
error: use of deleted function 'task::task(const task&)'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1c7fajqn8

Which compiler is right here?

P.S. There is a related question [Why must the return type of a coroutine be move-constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429881/why-must-the-return-type-of-a-coroutine-be-move-constructible) but

- the issue there was fixed in GCC 10.2, while the example from this question is still valid in GCC 11 and trunk;
- this question asks about `co_await` requirements, while the other does not mention `co_await` at all;
- the other question is about move-constructor only, while here the latest GCC demands copy-constructor.

Comment: You might be interested in following bug on the clang compiler: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53098

Comment: @JVApen Note that [the OP themselves posted that bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641441/4573247).

Comment: "*the issue there was fixed in GCC 10.2, while the example from this question is still valid in GCC 11 and trunk;*" Then it wasn't fixed, was it? "*this question asks about co_await requirements, while the other does not mention co_await at all;*" Why do you believe that's relevant? `co_await` has nothing to do with the nature of the return value. "*the other question is about move-constructor only, while here the latest GCC demands copy-constructor.*" Why do you think that matters?

Answer (score 1):

It is a compiler [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99575). Specifically,

*If o would be a prvalue, the temporary materialization conversion (7.3.4) is applied* -- [co_await 7.6.2.3](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf#subsubsection.7.6.2.3)

Which basically means it should be constructed in place using RVO.