# Why is the move constructor not invoked when returning an rvalue?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have created a class `Animal`:

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal() = default;
    Animal(Animal&& a) = delete;
    Animal(Animal& a) = delete;

    Animal& operator=(Animal&& a) = delete;
    Animal& operator=(Animal& a) = delete;
};

Animal func1() {
    return Animal();
}

Animal func2() {
    Animal a {};
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    Animal a1 = func1();
    Animal a2 = func2();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why `func1()` works fine: `return Animal()` creates an rvalue object and I initialize `a1` with this object in the `main` function; as I see it, it is equal to

```
Animal a1 = func1()
         ==
Animal a1 = Animal&& temp   //(I wrote type in assignment for clarifying)
```

and I have read that the return value is an rvalue; however, in `func2` I get an error that ‘copy constructor is deleted’ not the move constructor, why?

Comment: In your "equal to" example, I think you meant to use temp in the first line, instead of `1a`.

Comment: Probably [copy-elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Comment: your code will not work in cases where elisions are disabled and for sure is not a portable code. As it's explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972908/c-copy-constructor-activation-in-return-by-vlaue) c++93 and before will try to use copy constructors to return from a method and move ctors will be used in c++11-18 if exists, otherwise copy. 
And since you deleted all of them, your code will be depended on compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
 Animal a1 = func1();
```

The call expression `func1()` is an **rvlalue** of type `Animal`. And from C++17 onwards, due to [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The **copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible**:

> - In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:

That is, the object is constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. That is, in this case(for C++17), there is no need of a copy/move constructor to be available. And so this statement works.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
Animal a2 = func2();
```

Here from [non mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations),

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still **must be present and accessible** (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed:

> - In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type.

That is, the copy/move constructors are required to exist(that is these ctors must be present and accessible) but since you've explicitly marked them as **deleted** this statement fails with the [error](https://onlinegdb.com/p_Ws9ITJV):

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Animal::Animal(Animal&&)’
```

The error can also be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/p_Ws9ITJV)

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 there is a new set of rules about temporary materialization.

In a simple explanation an expression that evaluates to a prvalue (a temporary) doesn't immediately create an object, but is instead a recipe for creating an object. So in your example `Animal()` doesn't create an object straight away so that's why you can return it even if the copy and move constructors are deleted.

In your main assigning the prvalue to `a` triggers the temporary materialization so the object is only now created directly in the scope of `main`. Throught all of this there is a single object so there is no operation of copy or move.