# c++ return value optimization and returning complex class problem

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics

according to [This question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972908/c-copy-constructor-activation-in-return-by-vlaue) when we return an object from a function, it is compiler and c++ version dependent how it is returned, it could be moved, copied or elided.
imagine I have complex classes such as(could be even more complicated)

```
class Basket{
    public:
        Basket (); // ctor 
        ~Basket (); // dtor
        Basket (Basket &); // copy ctor
        Basket (Basket &&); // move ctor
        Basket & operator= (Basket &); // copy assignment
        Basket & operator= (Basket &&); // move assignment
        // getter setters
    private:
        vector<Products> product_list;
        vector<Liked> liked_list;
}

class Customer
{               // Note: All methods have side effects
  public: 
  
    Customer (); // ctor 
    ~ Customer (); // dtor
    Customer (Customer &); // copy ctor
    Customer (Customer &&); // move ctor
    Customer & operator= (Customer &); // copy assignment
    Customer & operator= (Customer &&); // move assignment
    // getter setters
    
  private:
    vector<int*> some_ptrs;
    vector<Adress> adress_list;
    CustomerInfo customer_info;
    vector<Basket> basket;
};
```

```
Customer get_customer(int id) {
    Customer customer = db.get_customer(id);
    return customer;
}
```

in cases where my copy and move semantics have side effects and it's not clear which method is used, how can I write a code that's consistent and efficient?
 What are the best practices to ensure that my code works as expected and efficient regardless of the implementation and the version of the c++ that is used.

Comment: Why do you have copy and move semantics for the `Basket` class? Why do you have a vector of `int` pointers in the `Customer` class? Is it a vector of arrays? Then use a vector of vectors instead. If you get rid of the pointers, then you could skip the copy and move operations for the `Customer` class as well.

Comment: Also, the `get_customer` function could be reduced to simply `return db.get_customer(id);`, which would definitely invoke RVO (though hopefully the compiler, with optimizations enabled, might do it anyway).

Comment: The linked Q&A says the object will be moved once or twice, never copied. (Unless you use C++98.)

Comment: Your class shouldn't have custom destructor and copy and move operations. Those are a rather advanced tool, which you shouldn't need to use often. If you were using those to dynamically allocate memory for those `int*`, replace them with containers or smart pointers. But if you do need custom copy and move operations, the copy ones should accept const refs, and the move ones should be noexcept.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware of all of the things you said but I speak hypothetically here. Language allows me to do these, so i did simply :)

Comment: Why do you think difference of return method choice might be a problem? What are you trying to guard against? As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: Just because something is "allowed" by the language doesn't mean you *must* use it... :) The [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is rather important when it comes to programming. Simple code is easier to read, understand, maintain and debug. The more complex your code becomes, the harder everything will get.